# tomcat +oci +oracle11

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, oracle-call-interface

Spec
Jdk1.6
Tomcat 6
Oracle 11g
ojebc6.jar

Advance users always say that Oracle performs best on type(2) OCI rather then on type(4) Thin
drivers.

Can Some body explain me the Steps to create a JNDI on Tomcat ( use OCI  + tnsnames.ora)

I did some Configuration and get error....

> ```
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.getLibraryVersionNumber()I
> ```

Can somebody explain me why this is Happening ???

with regards
karthik

Comment: If you wish to use the non-thin oracle client, then you have to have `libocijdbc11.so` on your `java.library.path` (if it is Unix OS).